# How to get the clients ip address from the server?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have problem where I can't get the clients Ip from the server to store it into a variable then into a dictionary. I've tried to use getAddress() but it's not working it give a message says " can't find symbol" .

```
try {
        DatagramSocket IN_socket = new DatagramSocket(3000);
        DatagramSocket OUT_socket = new DatagramSocket(8000);
        IN_socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        Inet4Address addrs = DatagramSocket.getAddress() ;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
```

Comment: "...and it always gave me an error."  -- Are you going to tell us what the error is, or just keep us in suspense?

Comment: Please add your stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object [`java.net.DatagramSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) doesn't have a `getAddress()` method, instead there is [`getInetAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getInetAddress--):

> public [`InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) getInetAddress()
>
> Returns the address to which this socket is connected. Returns null if the socket
>   is not connected. If the socket was connected prior to being closed,
>   then this method will continue to return the connected address after
>   the socket is closed.
>
> Returns: the address to which this socket is connected.